# iptables port REDIRECT works locally but not from outside

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, port

I have a server that can only listen to port 23006. I want to access it from outside and on port 443.

I have systemctl setup:

```
$ sudo sysctl --system
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-pid-max.conf ...
* Applying /usr/lib/sysctl.d/99-protect-links.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf ...
* Applying /etc/sysctl.conf ...
kernel.pid_max = 4194304
fs.protected_fifos = 1
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_regular = 2
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 1
```

If I run some another test server to listen on port 443 it works and I can access it from outside. But it is just a test server and not my actual server program.

If I run socat:

```
sudo nohup socat TCP-LISTEN:443,pktinfo,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:23006
```

it works and I can access it from outside. But my server does not see the actual IP address of the client.

If I run curl on port 23006 my actual server reponds:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:23006
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.24.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

If I run this iptables command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 23006
```

then I can also access my server through port 443 but ONLY from local:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:443
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.24.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is: I cannot access my server from outside on port 443. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect ***incoming*** traffic, use the `PREROUTING` chain.

Furthermore if you want redirection, it is suggested to use the `mangle` or `nat` table instead.

Comment: Nope, INPUT chain is NOT for NAT. For DNAT (which REDIRECT is a flavour of) it's `PREROUTING` chain in `nat` table.

Comment: @Tomek ah you're right. Had a brainfart there.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 23006
```